# Symfony2 - APYDataGridBundle - Translate title in Entity annotations

Tags: symfony

can someone give me a hint about how to set the translated title in the annotations used by the APYDataGridBundle.
 I have already taken a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/Abhoryo/APYDataGridBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/columns_configuration/annotations/column_annotation_property.md) but the 3 lines of explanation doesn't really explain to me what I need to do to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Do you want to translate titles in thead section? There is no need to do that. I'm using same bundle and it's automatically translates that fields. Just add translation to lang.yml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not as well documented as it could be, but a quick look at the [twig template code](https://github.com/Abhoryo/APYDataGridBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/blocks.html.twig), lines 68-81, reveals the exact methodology: Your translation variable is the prefixTitle of your grid object (if defined, default value is an empty string) concatenated with your specified title for the column in the annotation, so [prefixTitle][columnTitle]

You are also free to add a second translation variable called [prefixTitle][columnTitle]_abbr that just gets used in the table header, but for example in the search menu the non-abbreviated version (without _abbr suffix) gets used. This is optional.